# How to check digit from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have getting string. I want to check string have any digit.
The string may be -

```
var val="1";  or  val=",,"; or val = "1,2,0";
```

I want to check if val have any digit.

Answer (score 3):

```
function hasDigit(yourString) {
  return yourString.match(/\d/) !== null;
}
```

Here's a fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VpLgG/

Answer (score 0):

You can use yourInputString.match(/[0-9]/g), or what Jonah has specified. This will return null if there are not digits else it will return the values present inside the string that will match separated by comma.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript side :

```
if (/\d/.test(val)) {
    // do something
}
```

Not really useful but required to get attention apparently ([demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/wared/D7G25/))...

```
function hasDigit(val) {
    return /\d/.test(val);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test